# css grid how to expand element take up remaining space or scroll if too large?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Goal is to build a page the **expands** the **height** of the main content to remaining height of page but **not to exceed the visible area**.  Instead it should max out and start **vertically scrolling instead**.

Is this possible in css grid without using `max-height: 80vh` for example?  I don't always know what the max-height should be. (`.app-main` is large content that should expand but be capped at remaining height and then start scrolling vertically.)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  height: 100vh;
}

.app-main {
  height: 1800px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<section class="app-main">
  <p>
    my large content
  </p>
</section>
<footer>
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: if I may, the *contents* of the `app-main` will be having large height right? so you should set `height: 1800px` on `.app-main p` - now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height on the children of section will achieve what you want. For example:

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  height: 100vh;
}

.app-main {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.app-main p {
  height: 1200px;
}
```